# Subdomain involuntarily redirects to primary domain after logging in or saving

Tags: 6, redirection

I made a development site using development.breinwijzer.be as subdomain. After I've logged in, I'm already back at my primary domain www.breinwijzer.be.

- I tried different browsers.
- I cleared caches.
- I cleared browser caches.
- I checked the settings.php file of the development site to see if I have the correct database set for the development site.

Other than this, I'm clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `settings.php` someone uncommented `$base_url` and put the primary domain of the site as a value. Changing the value into the subdomain I was working in solved the issue.

Comment: if the issue has been solved completely, consider marking your own answer as solution as it would help others looking with similar issues.

Comment: It's 11 hrs too early to do that

Comment: I had the same problem, and this is exactly what the reason and the fix was. Thank you.